# How to change the font size and color of a Telerik MVC Chart title?

Tags: telerik-mvc

Can it be done? I did a lot of research and couldn't find anything.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there isn't any settings for that in the Chart API, but what when I inspected Telerik ASP.NET MVC demo page I found out the text element that is used on the title.

With some JavaScript you could change the title font size and color easily.

[image: DOM view of the Telerik Chart demo]

This is a jQuery example:

```
$('#chart').find('text:nth(0)').css('font-size', '30px').css('text', 'red')
```

First I'll get the chart control with id and then find the title which is the first text element. Then I'll place my own css styling.

This isn't the optimal way to do this and it is basically a hack, but if nothing else cannot be done then this might be your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have a different approach to this since we ran into the same thing but with trying to bold the title... Kendo MVC Chart API now gives you access to the font tag which it pushes into the style tag. Well what we did was just close that element and add our own element(s) to the style tag:

```
.Title(t => t.Text("My Chart Title").Font(";font-weight:bolder;"))
```

As you can see below it renders the style and in turn bolds the title text.

[image: Rendered HTML]

Answer (score 0):

**in razor page add this code for the category in chart**

```
.CategoryAxis(axis => axis.Categories(model => model.MonthName)                                                                                         
                          .Labels(labels => labels.Font("tahoma").Color("red").Margin(15))                                                                                                  
                          .Labels(labels => labels.Rotation(-90))                                                                                                  
                          .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(true)))                                                  
))
```